# Manage ID's inserted an in input box seperated by commas

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an "input box" where you should insert various ID's seperated by commas (1,2,3,4...etc) where later on I would like to manage these ID's in a MYSQL query.

How is the best way to do this? 
How can I later use the variable in the MYSQL query?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: use explode(','. $_POST['ids'])

Comment: Should be a `,` not a `.` in @AdRock's comment: `explode(',', $_POST['ids'])`. If you need any more info than that, you'll need to tell us *what* you want to do with the list of IDs in PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Im using an XML where I get the parameter value (1,2,3). These ID's are suppose to go into a query which could look like this for example: 

    `SELECT * FROM test
    WHERE ID's NOT LIKE 1 AND NOT LIKE 2 AND NOT LIKE 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to manipulate comma separated value in MySql.

Ex :

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d') --Returns 0 if not matched within given string
```